# Check nullability vs throw NullExceptions

Tags: c#, error-handling, nullable-reference-types

I have been trying to understand the difference between two approaches and have always got confused so thought of asking this question here.

Consider following code,

```
public string? MyMethod(object parameter)
{
    return parameter.Something(); // access something on object assuming return type is same
}
```

Now there're two common possibilities to guard this code

This, which may cause exception handling/null handling before calling (also consider possibly making user aware of any underlying exceptions that may be thrown by `Something()`.

```
public string? MyMethod(object parameter)
{
    if(parameter == null) throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
    // or even better C# 10 ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parameter);
    return parameter.Something(); // assuming return type is same
}
```

Or

Won't need a lot of null/exception handling for caller of this method

```
public string? MyMethod(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter != null)
        return parameter.Something(); // assuming return type is same
    return null;
    // or to make it even easier
    // return parameter?.Something() 
}
```

Out of these two approaches which one would be more sensible considering below conditions; Not sure should that matter or if there's one size fits all, but I would also like to understand the trade-off to consider when deciding.

1. This code is used as internal code, where use-cases are fairly well known or expectations can be set **vs** as a public library where use case may not be so obvious.
2. Considering impact from performance/maintenance perspective. I had read some articles about throw catch performance impact but was not sure if that's a relevant consideration?
3. What if `MyMethod` is a public vs private method? i.e. Controlled usage vs uncontrolled usage
4. I do understand that both methods imply different meaning and in general it is better to be cleaner in intent, but what if from user's perspective it wouldn't matter if the `parameter` or the operation on parameter produces null. (for eg., assume this was being done for `implicit operator`). So basically ease of use vs rigidity (without making it sound negative)
5. Would it make any difference if the return type of `Something` is never null, but due to null checking I may have to return a default nullable value while with exception thrown I may never have to return a nullable value?

Comment: This is too hypothetical to review. If you have a concrete project where this question surfaces, feel free to post it.

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at [SoftwareEngineering](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/), but before posting there please [**follow their tour**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If the method is part of a public API, you do not know whether the users of your library are using it in a correct way. Protecting your API with exceptions is a common practice.

It is however not the task of exceptions to catch programming errors. If the method is an implementation detail (i.e., if it is private or internal), then you will detect an unexpected null value while debugging or unit testing. Handle the error by **fixing your code** (not by throwing an exception)!

It can also be a valid approach to return an error condition from a method through the return value and let the caller handle it in an appropriate way. Either by returning a Boolean value, a null value, by setting an error flag in a returned object or by returning a special error value.

Examples:

```cs
// Dictionaries
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) {
    // okay
} else {
    // key not found
}
// But
var result = dict[key]; // Throws if key not found. It is not expected that you
// catch this exception here. Use the indexer only for keys that you know are in
// the dictionary.

// Strings
int i = s.IndexOf("x");
if (i >= 0) {
    // okay, substring found.
} else { // i is -1
    // Substring not found.
}
```

You may also want to tell the user about an error condition, but you do not want to include UI logic into business logic. Then it makes sense to tell the caller (in the UI tier) about the problem trough a return value (e.g., by returning null).

```cs
string? file = businessLogic.GetFile(settings);
if (file is null) {
    MessageBox.Show("File not found, please select an existing file.");
} else {
    // Use file
}
```

An exception is not efficient. If it happens exceptionally, this is not a problem. If it happens in a tight loop, however, this will degrade performance. As the word "exception" implies, it must be used to notify exceptional, i.e., rare, conditions only.

Exceptions must not be used as part of the normal program flow. They are reserved for unexpected or invalid conditions.